# Symmetric distribution of a Gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I have a general question concerning Gaussian processes.
Is any Gaussian process $Z$ having a symmetric distribution? 
(I am interested in some classes of diffusion processes and wonder can I apply the results for symmetric distribution processes).
I would be very grateful for references if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a symmetric distribution? That for any $t>0$, the $\mathbb P(Z_t>0)=\mathbb P(Z_t<0)$? It seems to me that standard Brownian motion would satisfy this

Comment: Yes, my question concerns the standard meaning of symmetric distribution. It seems to be the same, but I could not find any reference which states it for sure...Anyway, thanks!